# Create own $_SESSION-like variable?

Tags: php, superglobals

This is me being a bit nitpicky, but I really like the ease in which `$_SESSION` works. So I was wondering if there is a way for me to make my rows in a database work like that. It was easy for me to make a superglobal, so for example `$_DATA['address']` would return the address saved in the database of the user currently logged in. The obvious problem is that when I write something to `$_DATA['whatever']` it automatically would write it to the database. That would be easy in C#, what I'm used to, but in PHP there seems to be no normal get/set functionality. Is there any way for me to accomplish what I'm hoping to do?

Comment: I really *really* think you should not want to do that. Globals result in terrible headaches and will set your cat on fire. Just think about having to debug / test something like that.

Comment: Create your data variable (or mis-/reuse one of the superglobals), and glue on some get/set logic using a derived `ArrayObject`.

Comment: It's not possible to create your own superglobals. I can't comment on this without mentioning that [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) exists, but for <insert deity here>'s sake **don't**. Just inject data properly, maintain encapsulation/testability/sanity and pretend this never happened. I promise I will forget about it if you do.

Comment: well I'd go for a new class to act as $_DATA(conceptually). while in setter method of that class I could add the code to update the related column in database.

Comment: consider chdb or Hidef or APC

Comment: @DaveRandom Actually, it should be `/((<insert deity here>)'s)+ | FFS/` to include people with multiple deities or no deities.

Comment: just create static methods on a CurrentUser class. It will be globally accessible and you can set it up so it transparently persists and restores itself

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class and give it some static helper functions

For example:

```
class CurrentUser {

     protected static $currentUser;
     protected static function getCurrentUser(){
          if (!static::$currentUser){
                // get the current user from db and assign it to the currentUser Property
          }
          return static::$currentUser;
     }
     public static function get($property){
          return isset(static::getCurrentUser()->$property)?static::$currentUser->$property:null;
     }

     public static function set($property, $value){
          // make sure we have the current user
          $user = static::getCurrentUser();
          if ($user){
               $user->$property = $value;
               // save the user to the database.
          }
     }
}
```

To use then you would just say

```
echo CurrentUser::get("address");

echo CurrentUser::set("address", "123 anystreet, anytown US 12345");
```

Comment: I gave you an UP-vote, because this is actually a reasonable solution to the OP's question-- moving the functionality into functions or object methods, and calling them that way.  Much better than trying to use superglobals in the way he described.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework like Yii which has classes like CActiveRecord which map on to rows in a database.

```
$u = User::model()->findByPk(1);
$u->username = "fred";
$u.save();
```

If you keep a reference to the object you can save the record each time you want.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord